# Why does Riker pronounce "charade" two different ways?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, production

I learned this interesting fact from a comment on a YouTube video yesterday. In this scene from [*Future Imperfect*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Future_Imperfect_(episode)), notice how Jonathan Frakes pronounces "charade" (at 1:55):

Compare to how he said it here in the episode promo:

[/ʃəˈɹɑːd/ vs /ʃɚˈɹeɪd/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/charade#Pronunciation)

Why the difference? Was this scene dubbed over later or re-shot? Did that kind of dubbing happen a lot in Star Trek? I could not find anything about it on Memory Alpha, which makes me think it might be commonplace and not notable.

Comment: Does this really keep you up at night?! o.O

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No? I find it amusing. O.o

Comment: It's not been reshot. His head position is *identical* if you look at the starfield behind him. That means it has to have been a redub, presumably for a UK audience.

Comment: @Valorum Good catch. I thought the frame rate in the full scene was low, which I often notice in UK videos.

Comment: @zabeus: Funny, the frame rate in your things is high ;)

Comment: Off topic, but I was amused that the still image on the two videos (ie before you hit 'play') are showing virtually identical scenes -- over the shoulder shot of Riker talking to Data. One is over Riker's shoulder and the other is over Data's, but other than that they're the same. They even look like they're standing at about the same spot on the bridge.

Comment: Is one of them really _TOM RIKER?!?_

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The scene from the promo was most likely raw footage, taken directly from the boom mike on set. The line from the actual episode was then redubbed using a technique called ADR ([Automated dialogue replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubbing_(filmmaking)#ADR.2Fpost-sync)) where words that are slurred or pronounced with a colloquial accent can be corrected later.

According to the show's '*dialogue rerecording mixer*', Chris Haire, some episodes had as much as 50% of ***all*** dialogue being redubbed after the fact (and not just the lines spoken by people in latex makeup either).

> *Still, technical problems are not the only cause of dialogue replacement. The producers place a lot of emphasis on the clarity of speech, and that means not only rising above extraneous noises, but also steering through strong accents, masks and false teeth. 'It's a very dialogue-orientated show in addition to the sound effects.' says Haire. 'A typical Star Trek episode averages about 150 lines of ADR, and a heavy show will be in the 300s. 300 lines is about half--or maybe more--of the total. That, however, is down to the fact that the producers want every word to be pristine; clean and perfectly spoken. **If a word is slurred or its pronunciation is too colloquial, then the actor will be brought in to redo the line***.
>
> <sub><sup>[Richard Buskin visits LA's Modern Sound, home to a decade's sci-fi sound](http://filmsound.org/studiosound/pp_startrek.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: +1 Also, just to note, I don't think it's at all unusual for a single person to use both pronunciations of that word at different times. I know I use both.

Comment: That quote seems to be saying it's more like 25% of lines of dialogue redubbed with ADR. It says a typical episode has about 150 lines of ADR, a "heavy" show in the 300s, and 300 is about half of the total. That'd place a typical episode at about a quarter of dialogue ADR-redubbed.

Comment: @user2357112 - You're right of course. See edit.

Comment: +1 Also, as an ex-audio engineer, I'm fairly sure that the audio from the first clip is recorded through a boom microphone, and the second is from close-miked ADR. You can hear more "air" or reverb in the first, while the latter sounds like it has more bass (an artefact of close-miking).

Comment: I have no idea, but it sounds legit.

Comment: And given all of that, they still couldn't decide how they wanted actors to say "futile".

Comment: @J... - I think you mean fewtul.

Comment: @Sparhawk I'm not a professional lip reader, but I'd say the second clip is the original audio - he very much looks to be voicing `ɑ` and not `ā`.  Air and reverb are easy to match-in in post - and the punchy compressed sound for the trailer (that has to survive over music, etc, which is not present in the episode) is also easy to post in.

Comment: @J... TBH, I can't deduce anything from the movement of his lips. You are correct that you can artificially add air/reverb later, but in my experience that's extremely rare. Many productions *want* that close-miked sound. In the second, I didn't notice compression so much (that's not a feature of close-miking), but there's definitely more bottom end. That *is* a feature of close-miking. It's easy enough to add post, but I can't imagine why they'd want that for the trailer. Having said all that, the quality of the audio is poor enough that I have very little confidence in any of my claims. :)

Comment: @Sparhawk I guess I meant that if they're using *most* of the boom mic audio and are doing an ADR then they're going to try to match the new audio to what's already in the scene. The extra bottom end and "close-mic" sound in the trailer would sound odd in a normal scene during the episode - you need it to sound like a person in an environment to get the right feel for the flow of the scene. For the trailer, though, you want a close, punchy sound to cut through the drama. Trailers are also commercials and, as such, are naturally heavily compressed to compete with the rest of the noisy interval.

Comment: This entire discussion is just a futile charade.

Answer (score -1):

This has always bugged me. I seem to remember Riker saying *Sha-RAHD* in the episode itself, perhaps when it first aired.

But now it seems that he said it in the promo only. Is it possible that the dialog was ADR'd AFTER the initial airing of the episode, or does it not work like that? That is to say, once an episode is done and aired, then it's DONE.

**EDIT:** According to a trivia tidbit on IMDB (Alternate Versions):

> In the original broadcast and the Columbia House VHS version, when
> Riker discovers the Romulan deception and says, "Shall we end this
> charade," he pronounces the word "sha-rad". This line was later ADR'd
> by Jonathan Frakes for the DVD to say "charade" pronounced "sha-RADE".

Comment: Could you try and find some better evidence to support this than IMDb? If so you can [edit] it into your answer.

Comment: My concern is that IMDB is often incorrect. For example, on the same page it states confidently that it's a goof that "*Romulan ships do not use warp coils. They use an artificial quantum singularity for propulsion"* which is simply wrong.